# Search order by query string

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I use following working mysql query:

```
SELECT Nom_Appellations
FROM appellations
WHERE Nom_Appellations LIKE '%saint%'
LIMIT 8
```

And I have this result :

```
Lussac-Saint-Emilion
Montagne-Saint-Emilion
Puisseguin-Saint-Emilion
Saint-Emilion
Saint-Emilion grand cru
Saint-Emilion grand cru classé
```

But I want to ORDER by string "saint" pertinence like this:

```
Saint-Emilion
Saint-Emilion grand cru
Saint-Emilion grand cru classé
Lussac-Saint-Emilion
Montagne-Saint-Emilion
Puisseguin-Saint-Emilion
```

How I can get data order by featured string ?

Comment: just add this to your query `ORDER BY 'Nom_Appellations' ASC`

Comment: is it that you just want those starting saint first then order normally?

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the first appearance of `saint` in `Nom_Appellations`:

```
SELECT Nom_Appellations
FROM appellations
WHERE Nom_Appellations LIKE '%saint%'
ORDER BY LOCATE('saint', lower(Nom_Appellations))
LIMIT 8;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need a second parameter in order by to keep ties sorted alphabetically?

Comment: @xQbert . . . The original query doesn't have an `ORDER BY`, so it doesn't seem important to the OP.  Of course adding `, Nom_Appellations` to the `ORDER BY` might be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Nom_Appellations
FROM appellations
WHERE Nom_Appellations LIKE '%saint%'
ORDER BY case when left(nom_Appellations,5)= 'Saint' then 0 else 1 end, nom_appellations
LIMIT 8;
```

Assuming you just want those starting Saint first, and the rest in alphabetical order.